# Recovering Data from a Laptop Hardrive

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, mount, data-recovery

My laptop stopped working suddenly. I would like to clone its hardrive (size 500 gb) before I send it for repairs. The laptop had a dual boot windows/ ubuntu setup with grub bootloader.

To clone the harddrive I wanted to use testdisk.

The problem is when I connect the hard drive to another laptop running Linux Mint it doesn't mount the hard drive.

Using Gparted shows an unallocated 500gb harddrive at  `/dev/sdb`  but it cannot mount it.

Running  `sudo /fdisk -l`  gives the following output.

[image]

Then I tried   `fsck /dev/sdb` and the output is as follows.

[image]

Finally I tried  `dmesg|tail`  and I got the following output.

[image]

At this point I am out op options. I would appreciate any help/suggestions/comments. Please let me know if you need more clarifications.

Thank you

Comment: `fsck /dev/sdb` attempts to repair the *entire disk,* but `fsck` should be used on a *filesystem,* such as `/dev/sdb1`. If you attempted the same with `mount`, you'd run into a similar issue. Also, TestDisk is a data recovery tool, not a disk-cloning tool. For cloning your disk, you'd do better with `dd` or [Clonezilla.](http://clonezilla.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a data recovery tool like `ddrescue` to recover each partition or the entire disk.

http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue

Answer (score 1):

ddrescue is a cloning tool, not a data recovery one.

Use ddrescue or HDDSuperClone. The latest is more recent than ddrescue and offers some benefits, but it currently has a much lower base of users who tested it.

So, as this is your first attempt, I would suggest you using ddrescue with a logfile. Clone the whole drive /dev/sdX or the partition containing the data /dev/sdXn that you'll attempt to recovery later.

Be careful to read the documentation very carefully before using ddrescue as doing mistakes may loose your data forever if you mixes the drives. 
You can use `hdparm -I /dev/sdX | less` to double check that you're not mixing input and output drives ; check the model and serial number of each.

If the cloning process hits bad sectors and becomes very slow, you can play with ddrescue's parameters, like setting -i to skip bad areas, -n to avoid splitting in the first pass, a.s.o.
Understanding reverse cloning is important too.

Utilities like fsck or chkdsk are more oriented to repair small errors in file systems, but if the drive is defective, they can do more harm than good.

It might also be cheaper calling a company specialized in data recovery as this is daily routine for them. Mine would ask about 300 USD for a successful logical data recovery of such drive. Data recovery companies have better equipment (hardware imagers, more powerful softwares, ...) and experience but I also understand if you want to try it yourself.